Failed to find default application for the content type 'application/octet-stream'
I recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.10. After the upgrade, I tried to access my 1TB hard disk. Once I clicked the hard-disk folder, I got:
Failed to find default application for the content type 'application/octet-stream'

Now I can't access the disk. What can I do to get this working again?

I just got the same error.
In my case the reason was that I did mount as root, then logout from my local account, logged in again, and when I clicked the hard disk folder I got the same error:
Failed to launch "volume_name"
Failed to find default application for the content type 'application/octet-stream'

All I had to do was umount the HDD as root: sudo umount /media/root/1TBHDD
